# Instantiation does not stop at count and adds one extra. Solution?

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, count, instantiation

So, this is my code. There's *instantiate* code within **SpawnObj1()** & **SpawnObj2()**. The **prefabs** inside **SpawnObj()**(**1** & **2**) spawns properly but **SpawnObj1** spawns *one extra* **prefab** when the *count* is at **5**. How do I stop instantiation exactly at that *count*?

```
 public void Spawner()
     {
         if (objCount < 5)
         {
             SpawnObj1();
         }
 
         if (objCount >= 5)
         {
             SpawnObj2();
         }
     }
```

BTW, **objCount** is *objCount ++* within **SpawnObj()**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you increment "objCount" in SpanwObject1() and in SpawnObject2().
If we follow the code when objCount is 4

```
objCount is 4
SpawnObject1() // increment the objCount
objCount is 5

So the condition objCount >= 5 is valid here in the same call of "Spawner()"
SpawnObject2()
```

An easy fix is to modify your code like this :

```
public void Spawner()
 {
     if (objCount < 5)
     {
         SpawnObject1();
     }
     else if (objCount >= 5)
     {
         SpawnObject2();
     }
 }
```

with this fix, the SpawnObject2() won't be called just after SpawnObject1 when objCount is 4. You can also add a return after each "SpawnObject..."

Comment: WORKS!!! Thank you so much. I don't have much coding knowledge. I never would have guessed that something simple as this changes many things.